# Pyinstaller: Images fail to extract

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I run the build command and everything appears to build correctly until I try to launch the exe and this message pops up:

[image]

Here is my spec file, I am not sure why it appears to be combing the file path with both images.

```
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['TripCalc.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BennySM.ico', 'C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BgSM.gif')],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='TripCalc',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=False , 
icon='C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\Benny.ico')
```

I tried adding the files beside datas:

```
('Benny.ico', 'C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BennySM.ico', 'data', 'BgSM.gif', 'C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BgSM.gif', 'data')
```

But it would not build with the `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

I followed the example from this post on how to add the file path to the main python file. [Bundling data files with PyInstaller --onefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)

I am able to build the exe and run it with the images commented out. Any help would be much appreciated.

When I get the Value Error message I setup the spec file with the following:

```
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['TripCalc.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[('Benny.ico','C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BennySM.ico','data','BgSM.gif','C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BgSM.gif','data')],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='TripCalc',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=False , 
icon='C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\Benny.ico')
```

Error window

[image: Build -Value Error]

With those changes to the spec file everything builds but the [failed to launch script pops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHFSs.png) up when launching the exe. If they got packed with the exe they should be locationed in the temp file in app data correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ([DOCS](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files)):

> **Adding Data Files:**
>
> To have data files included in the bundle, provide a list that describes the files as the value of the `datas=` argument to `Analysis`. The list of data files is a list of `tuples`. Each tuple has *two* values, both of which must be strings:
>
> The first string specifies the file or files as they are in this system now.
>   The second specifies the name of the folder to contain the files at run-time.

So your `datas` line will need to be something like:

```
datas=[
    ('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BennySM.ico', 'data'),
    ('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BgSM.gif', 'data'),
],
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get around this for my own packages - which I try to make pip-installable - I have created a package that I'm calling [`stringify`](https://github.com/slightlynybbled/stringify).  The readme has the primary use case.

The idea of `stringify` is that you build your images (and other files types as well) into `.py` files which will be natively recognized by PyInstaller, requiring no `_MEIPASS` or `if sys.frozen` voodoo.  Your spec files become more portable and are more likely to work out of the box.

Additionally, if you package your files up for distribution on pypi, then someone uses your images in their package, *they* don't have to do any spec file manipulation.... it just works!

Within `setup.py` - or sometime before you distribute your package:

```
from stringify import stringify_py

stringify_py('images', 'my_package/images.py')
```

You can then import your images and replace your calls to `tkinter.PhotoImage` like so:

```
from images import img

# tkinter.PhotoImage(file='/path/to/img.png')  # <- your original call
tkinter.PhotoImage(data=img)  # <- new call
```

For an example of this method, you might reference my [tk_tools](https://github.com/slightlynybbled/tk_tools) package.  Have a look at `setup.py` and in `tk_tools/visual.py`.  Note how the images are also stored within `tk_tools/images.py`, which is imported and used directly.  PyInstaller will pick these up directly with the 'standard' spec file, reducing your mind share at build-time.