# File path for pyinstaller bundled images?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a one file exe with pyinstaller but I am not sure what the file paths for the images should be in the main python file.

At the top of my main python file I used the MEIPASS code:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
""" Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
try:
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
except Exception:
    base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

[From this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)

This is the current code I have for each image file:

```
root.iconbitmap('C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BennySM.ico')
filename = PhotoImage(file = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BgSM.gif')
```

I know these are not the best file paths but I am not sure what I need to add so the python file knows where to look. The images bundle with the exe and if I add the exe to the data file it finds the images and runs.

Thank you! I tried adding resource_path before but I was missing the file path in the define section at the top.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

**Question: How do I use a data file in a pyinstaller built program?**

Let's first assume that the python script is currently working when run as a script, and that the following line is in the script:

```
filename = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BgSM.gif')
```

This line indicates that the script is retrieving a file from a fixed directory (probably not best practice, but fine for an example), and turning that `.gif` file into a `PhotoImage()` object instance.  This will be our baseline.

There will need to be three things done to successfully use this file when our script is run as a `pyinstaller` built program.

**1. During the pyinstaller build, move the file to a known location**

This step is accomplished by adding a `datas` directive to the `.spec' file.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170011/7311767) for more info on how to do that.  But in short, this will be needed:

```
datas=[
    ('C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp\\BgSM.gif', 'data'),
    ...
],
```

Please note that there are two elements in the tuple.  The first element is the path of our `.gif` file as it exists in the working python script before we packaged it into a pyinstaller executable.  The second element of the tuple is the directory that the file will be in when the executable is run.

**2. At runtime, find our `.gif` file**

Here is the function from the example in the question, recast to use:

1. The absolute path from the example, when the script is run as a script or,
2. The path specified in the `datas` tuple when the script is run as a pyinstaller built program.

Code:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS,
        # and places our data files in a folder relative to that temp
        # folder named as specified in the datas tuple in the spec file
        base_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'data')
    except Exception:
        # sys._MEIPASS is not defined, so use the original path
        base_path = 'C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\TripApp'

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

**3. Recast the baseline to work in our pyinstaller built program**

So now that we can construct a path to our .`gif` file when run as a script, or as a pyinstaller built program, our baseline becomes:

```
filename = PhotoImage(file=resource_path('BgSM.gif'))
```