# Ive made an .exe file out of multiple .py files but i can't run it outside of the folder with every .py file in it

Tags: python, pygame, exe

Ive been working on a game with Pygame and i have multiple files and folders.
As you can see in the title, i have made the .exe file but the issue is that i cant run the .exe file outside of the folder, where everything else is also located in.

Comment: The problem is likely to be related to file paths, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42263060/2280890). You are being downvoted as your question lacks enough detail to be answerable. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

Your code is most likely referring to other file paths. Check if you are loading any images or sounds, because you might need to change the paths into specific paths in your code.

Just remember that if you want to share your code, you need to upload all of your working files.